# Magento2: Override Vendor Resource Model _afterLoad method

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, model, product-collection

I am trying to override the _afterLoad methods of the vendor class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` unsuccessfully.

In my custom module I edited the di.xml in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" 
                type="SG\Utilities\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</config>
```

Then I created the file `app/code/SG/Utilities/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace SG\Utilities\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{

    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        echo "called!";
        exit();
        if ($this->_addUrlRewrite) {
           $this->_addUrlRewrite();
        }

        $this->_prepareUrlDataObject();

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_collection_load_after', ['collection' => $this]);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

but the _afterLoad method is never called. What am I doing wrong?